# When to delete your own answer

Tags: discussion, deletion

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47112021/5031373), but I realized that my initial approach didn't work. I did some research and found [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112424/5031373).

I posted it as a second answer, since the answer was completely different from my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112113/5031373). Now my original answer has three net upvotes, but I know it's not on target and my second answer is the better one.

Should I delete the first answer?

Comment: No, edit it and delete the second answer.

Comment: No, keep both of them if they both works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should have done in the first place is edit your initial answer and post the new answer as a part of it. Like:

> **Edit:** Your new answer here

I usually only post a second answer when my first answer is hella wrong and have down-votes, then I just delete the first answer and post the new answer separately. But if my first answer is wrong but have up-votes, then I just edit and post the new answer as part of it.

In the edit you can simply make things clear, as to how this is better and why the old one is wrong, etc.